# How i can show many2one field all records on a form view instead drop down list in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo-10, odoo

How I can show many2one field all records on a form view instead drop down list in odoo 10.
For example, I have a Product category and Products.
When I select Product category from drop down list then all products belongs to that category shows on form view instead of a drop down list.

Comment: You can create one custom field which is m2m of categories and show all relavent products in that .

Answer (score 1):

Here I assume you have category id like,

```
category_id = fields.Many2one('product.category', "Product Category")
```

Add  **Many2many** of **product.product** field to your model for product records.

```
product_ids = fields.Many2many('product.product', "Products")
```

Now you need to define **onchange** on **category_id** field like.

```
@api.onchange('category_id')
    def onchange_product_category(self):
        if self.category_id:
            self.product_ids = [(5,)] # unlink all existing records of product
            product_recs = self.env['product.product'].search([('categ_id', '=', self.category_id.id)])
            self.product_ids = [(4, x) for x in product_recs] # link the product records of selected category
```

If you do not want to display your product records in list view you can use widget **many2many_tags** in the form view like,

```
<field name="product_ids" widget="many2many_tags"/>
```

It will work for you.